# Itertating over mysqli result not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I can't seem to get this to work if there is more than one row in the database.

It only processes the first row, and does it correctly based on the seat_category_id.

Maybe I can't use the "if" statements inside the "while" loop?

```
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM Seat 
        WHERE seat_order_id='$order->order_id'";        
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql)
              or die("Couldn't execute user query.");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $seat_user_id = $row['seat_user_id'];
    $seat_category_id = $row['seat_category_id'];
    $ticket_number = $row['ticket_number'];

    if ($seat_category_id=='1' || $seat_category_id=='2'){
        $sql="INSERT INTO Jackpots.mega_subscribers
                    (user_id,ticket_number)
                VALUES('$seat_user_id','$ticket_number')"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)
              or die("Couldn't execute user query.");  
    } elseif ($seat_category_id=='3'){
        $sql="INSERT INTO Jackpots.giga_subscribers
                            (user_id,ticket_number)
                VALUES('$seat_user_id','$ticket_number')"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)
              or die("Couldn't execute user query.");  
    }elseif ($seat_category_id=='4'){
        $sql="INSERT INTO Jackpots.tera_subscribers
                        (user_id,ticket_number)
                VALUES('$seat_user_id','$ticket_number')"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)
              or die("Couldn't execute user query.");  
    }     
}
```

Comment: You really ought to have your subscribers in one table with a column for holding whether they are `mega`, `giga` or `tera` subscribers. The queries would also then be much more straight forward. Check a tutorial on ___Normalisation___

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're overriding the value of `$result` that you are looping on inside the loop with these statements:

```
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)
          or die("Couldn't execute user query.");
```

Change them all to something like

```
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)
          or die("Couldn't execute user query.");
```

and the code should work fine.

Comment: Worked great Nick...I can't believe I missed that... :)